# Windows 7 Taskbar progress

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, taskbar

Quick question, I've developed a Forum specific C# WPF WebBrowser, for Windows 7.

I have completed so far for the Taskbar:

Tabbed thumbnails

Jumplists

Icon Overlay

Now as the WebBrowser uses the IE engine when a download is started the progress dialog is displayed, what i want is for the progress to be reflected in the Taskbar Button of my application.

Is this acheivable? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Heres a hint: use more tags when asking questions.  I helped out by adding some for you.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the progress or how to put it in the taskbar?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is something that [Scott Hanselman covered in one of his weekly source code blogs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode46JeffKeyRocksTaskbarMetersThatMonitorYourWindows7CPUAndMemoryAndDiskInTheTaskbar.aspx).

Not sure if that was what you were looking for or not.

Comment: While this answer is several years old and the link is helpful it would be better if you post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to put it in the Taskbar, i just need to catch the download progress so i can show the progress in the taskbar. Heres a snippet of how i get it to show navigation, the file copy is displayed without the need for code, shell is picking that up automatically.

```
  #region Background Worker

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = (double)e.ProgressPercentage / 100;

    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Paused;
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            this.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None;
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            this.backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i,i.ToString());
        }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

All thats needed for the Navigation is:

```
 private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == false)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

            TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal;
        }

        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count > 10 && tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
            UpdatePreviewBitmap(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
```

And taken from the Window Load Event:

```
        this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

        //
        TabbedThumbnail preview = new TabbedThumbnail(this.Handle, tabPage.Handle);
        //
        preview.TabbedThumbnailActivated += new EventHandler<TabbedThumbnailEventArgs>(preview_TabbedThumbnailActivated);
        preview.TabbedThumbnailClosed += new EventHandler<TabbedThumbnailEventArgs>(preview_TabbedThumbnailClosed);
        preview.TabbedThumbnailMaximized += new EventHandler<TabbedThumbnailEventArgs>(preview_TabbedThumbnailMaximized);
        preview.TabbedThumbnailMinimized += new EventHandler<TabbedThumbnailEventArgs>(preview_TabbedThumbnailMinimized);
        //
        TaskbarManager.Instance.TabbedThumbnail.AddThumbnailPreview(preview);
        //
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
        TaskbarManager.Instance.TabbedThumbnail.SetActiveTab(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        //

        scrollEventAdded = false;
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks